# i want to get the most visited 5 sections desc ordered

Tags: mysql, sql

lets assume that i have this MySql table structure

```
+----+------------+-------+
| id | section_id | views |
+----+------------+-------+
|  1 |      2     |   15  |
+----+------------+-------+
|  2 |      2     |   12  |
+----+------------+-------+
|  3 |      1     |   15  |
+----+------------+-------+
|  4 |      3     |   60  |
+----+------------+-------+
|  5 |      2     |  100  |
+----+------------+-------+
|  6 |      2     |   20  |
+----+------------+-------+
|  7 |      4     |   14  |
+----+------------+-------+
|  8 |      5     |   60  |
+----+------------+-------+
|  9 |      6     |   12  |
+----+------------+-------+
| 10 |      1     |   17  |
+----+------------+-------+
```

i want to get the most visited 5 sections desc ordered

i have tried `SELECT section_id FROM my_table ORDER by VIEWS DESC LIMIT 5`and have tried some other things like `sum()` but finally i got confused because i haven't use MySql for long time

your  help is very appreciated

Answer (score 1, accepted):

SQL:

```
  SELECT section_id, SUM(views)
    FROM my_table
GROUP BY section_id
ORDER BY SUM(views) DESC
   LIMIT 5
```

Result:

```
section_id  sum(views)
2           147
3           60
5           60
1           32
4           14
```

Playground:

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/6e3266/3/0

Answer (score 0):

if you don't want the id field then do aggregation with group by statement and limit together.

```
SELECT section_id, SUM(Views) as Views
FROM
     my_table
GROUP BY
    section_id
ORDER by
   VIEWS DESC
LIMIT 5;
```

Comment: hmmm @DanielAlder provides the answer I already provided minutes (at least more than 7 minutes) after and my answer doesn't get accepted.......... well glad it helped.....

Comment: you are right. but you don't know that at the time when I started the fiddle your answer didn't exist, and I also didn't see the aggregation in your answer, I was thinking your answer goes to another direction. anyway, I didn't accept the answer